# Android Studio InputFilterMinMax partially working

Tags: javascript, java, android, filter

i have 3 TextBoxes in one activity and want to set different MinMax filters for each. Now the two first are working but i can´t get the last one to function. I cannot type anything into it. Also

```js
 public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {  
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
```

here i get a message that InputFilterMinMax is never used and its getting greyed out. explanation??

Here is the Full Code:

```js
public class Akt4 extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_akt5);


        EditText editTextalt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextalt);
        editTextalt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("1", "65")});

        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText2.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("1", "180")});

        EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText3.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("130", "220")});

    }

    public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {
        private int min, max;

        public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) { 
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
            this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
            this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the input of any digit is not in your range.

For example if your input is 9, your filter will check and see that 9 is smaller than 130. Hence it is not allowed to input the digit. The bottom line is that using such a filter with a min number may be problematic. Perhaps you should perform the check only when you lose/gain focus for the EditText.

You can add a check for min characters for your `isInRange()` but I am not sure this what you want:

```
private boolean isInRange(int min, int max, int input) {
    // Assuming both numbers are positive (otherwise this might be wrong)
    if (String.valueOf(input).length() < String.valueOf(min).length()) {
        return true;
    }

    return max > min ? input >= min && input <= max : input >= max && input <= min;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I didn´t quite get the lose/gain part. So how do i have to write the code, that it works for editText3. Im new to Android Studio and Java :(